# set countdown timer by taking value from a datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am using this timer http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/

I can set the target value on script.js by

```
var note = $('#note'),
ts = new Date(2013, 05, 25),
newYear = true;
```

I want to set the value of `ts` by taking a value from datepicker. date picker has an option which is `onSelect :` hope we can define function here.

I want to define something like, when a user select a date from datepicker it will parse the date and put to the variable

```
var note = $('#note'),
ts = new Date(year, month, day),
newYear = true;
```

Thanks

**update: got one solution by writing the code http://pastebin.com/NHRuJ5mL**

Comment: jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: yes, jQuery UI datepicker want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you supposed, you can use the [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) function:

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

and get the selected value in the input field like:

```
$("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        alert(selectedDate)
    }
});
```

With the new value, you can split it in DD, MM, YYYY and you can reinitiate your countdown script.

Here is a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/6/

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using JQuery this should be pretty simple. You can do something like the following

```
 $('#dtTest').change(function(event) {
    ts = new Date($(this).val());
    newYear = true;
 });
```

Comment: Hi, we are so close to the solution.         http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/assets/js/script.js

So, i want to put the date picker code and set the ts value inside this script. I have tried your code different way but not succeed to figure out the case yet.

@Chris Wininger